# Unable to rebuild the Raid 1 Array (intel RST Raid 1) in BIOS and in OS(Ubuntu server 20.04.4)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, hard-drive, intel

we have HP server HP ProLiant ML10 Gen 9 with Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. We have enabled Raid 1 array for two HDD sized 2TB using Intel RST Raid configuration (which is an fake/firmware raid). **Now my goal is to replace the faulty Drive and rebuild the Raid 1 array.**

Below is the output of the Raid Status **cat /proc/mdstat**

```
surya@himalaya:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md126 : active raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
      1953511424 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sda[1](S) sdb[0](S)
      6320 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

Below is the output of the HDD info lsblk

```
surya@himalaya:~$ lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                         7:0    0 61.9M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1361
loop1                         7:1    0 67.9M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/22526
loop2                         7:2    0 55.5M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2284
loop3                         7:3    0 43.6M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/14978
loop4                         7:4    0 55.4M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2128
loop5                         7:5    0 43.6M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/15177
loop6                         7:6    0 67.2M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/21835
loop7                         7:7    0 61.9M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1376
sda                           8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
└─md126                       9:126  0  1.8T  0 raid1
  ├─md126p1                 259:0    0  1.1G  0 part  /boot/efi
  ├─md126p2                 259:1    0  1.5G  0 part  /boot
  └─md126p3                 259:2    0  1.8T  0 part
    ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0      253:1    0  1.7T  0 lvm   /home
sdb                           8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
└─md126                       9:126  0  1.8T  0 raid1
  ├─md126p1                 259:0    0  1.1G  0 part  /boot/efi
  ├─md126p2                 259:1    0  1.5G  0 part  /boot
  └─md126p3                 259:2    0  1.8T  0 part
    ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0      253:1    0  1.7T  0 lvm   /home
sr0                          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I used the below command to replace the faulty drive sdb as shown above.

**mdadm --manage /dev/md126 --fail /dev/sdb** and I shutdown the system and replaced the Harddrive in the same port.

now when I try to rebuild the array using this command **mdadm --manage /dev/md126 --add /dev/sdb** I get the below message.

```
root@himalaya:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md126 --add /dev/sdb
mdadm: Cannot add disks to a 'member' array, perform this operation on the parent container
```

now the output of **cat /proc/mdstat** is below.

```
root@himalaya:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md126 : active raid1 sda[0]
      1953511424 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/1] [U_]

md127 : inactive sda[0](S)
      3160 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

I also tried to enter the the Intel ROM option in BIOS using (Ctrl + i)
I have set the ***OROM UI normal delay to 4 seconds*** under **SATA configuration in BIOS setting**. but I couldn't get that screen to rebuild the array in BIOS. It would be a great help if someone can assist me on how to rebuild and restore the Raid 1 array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I answering my own question for everyone's benefit who has to deal with these type of fake raid controllers.

Here is what I found

Interestingly the **md126** is not the main RAID array here, it is **md127**, so all I did was re-adding this new drive to md127 with:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --force --add /dev/sdb
```

and the Raid started to rebuild itself.

now the results of ***cat/proc/mdstat*** are:

```
root@himalaya:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md126 : active raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
      1953511424 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
      6320 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

And this changes were reflected in the BIOS screen as well.
Intel RST RAID Volumes status was Normal.

**Below are the list of commands I used to restore this RAID 1 Array successfully.**

To check the raid status:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Removing the failed disk:
First we mark the disk as failed and then remove it from the array:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md126 --fail /dev/sdb
mdadm --manage /dev/md126 --remove /dev/sdb
```

Then power down the system and replace the new drive:

```
shutdown -h now
```

Adding the new hard drive: First you must create the exact same partitioning as on /dev/sda:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb
```

To check if both the harddrive are having the same partitioning:

```
fdisk -l
```

Next we add this drive to the RAID array (you can use md126 or md127 accordingly whichever is your main RAID array) below is the command I used:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --force --add /dev/sdb
```

That's it. You can now see the Raid started to rebuild.